# Android connectGatt with autoconnect true never called `onConnectionStateChange`

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My code sample is simple:

```
        connectButton.setOnClickListener {
            (getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager?)?.adapter?.getRemoteDevice(
                "44:73:D6:0A:EA:79"
            )?.let {
                Log.i(TAG, "trying to connect ${it.type}")
                val gatt = it.connectGatt(this, true, object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
                    override fun onConnectionStateChange(
                        gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
                        status: Int,
                        newState: Int
                    ) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "connection  status: $status, newState: $newState")
                    }
                }, TRANSPORT_AUTO)
                Log.i(TAG, "gatt is $gatt")
            }
```

With autoConnect=true, the log inside `onConnectionStateChange` never print.

```
I/BLE: trying to connect 2
D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: 44:73:D6:0A:EA:79, auto: true
    registerApp()
    registerApp() - UUID=6376adc0-c38c-4088-8da7-2175a640cec2
I/BLE: gatt is android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@415f1c6
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
```

with false, it prints three more lines

```
I/BLE: connection  status: 0, newState: 2
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=44:73:D6:0A:EA:79 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/BluetoothGatt: onConnectionUpdated() - Device=44:73:D6:0A:EA:79 interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
```

Tested on Huawei Mate20 with android 10 installed.

Edit: The peripheral is simulated by another android/iOS device, when connecting to a Bose earphone, this snippet seems fine, is there anything I can do to make the simulating device works as well?

Comment: I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @xurei nope, I switched to [Android beacon library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/) and use autoConnect=false when the device is discovered.

Answer (score 0):

The Android API lacks an "address type" parameter, which is a design mistake. Your peripheral advertises with a random resolvable address, and in that case it's a bad idea to connect directly using Bluetooth address. You should instead first perform a BLE scan and then connect to the device found. That way Android "learns" the address type from the advertising data, and can then connect using the correct address type.

Comment: Actully I am using the scan and connect apporach, the result is same. Above snippet is just a simplification.

Comment: Check the hci log then to see what happens.